# Show $\mathbb{P}_B \ll \mathbb{P}$ and find f s.t. $\mathbb{P}_B= f\mathbb{P}$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-probability, measurable-functions

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ and $B\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mathbb{P}(B)>0$. Show that for $\mathbb{P}_B(A)$ $:=\mathbb{P}(A|B)$ holds true $\mathbb{P}_B(A)\ll\mathbb{P}$ and find a density f such that $\mathbb{P}_B(A)=f\mathbb{P}$.

($\ll$ meaning "absolutely
continuous with respective to")

I thought about using the Radon-Nikodym-theorem and then f should be the Radon-Nikodym-derivative, but I am uncertain how to obtain f in this case.

Comment: Write out $P(A\mid B) = \int_{A}f\,dP$, and see what $f$ is.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$ should be equal to $\int_\Omega \mathbb{1}_{(A\cap B)} d\mathbb{P}$ I believe. And therefore $\mathbb{P}_B=1/\mathbb{P}(B)\cdot \int_\Omega \mathbb{1}_{(A\cap B)} d\mathbb{P}$?

Comment: Yes, so $f = 1/P(B) \cdot 1_{B}$.

Comment: Great thanks for the help!